# How do I gracefully close (terminate) Gradio from within gradio.Blocks()?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, gradio

I am new to using Gradio. I am attempting to modify Google Colaboratory Notebook (i.e. a Jupyter Notebook) for my own purposes.

I would like to terminate Gradio from within a `gradio.Column()` that performs my function `myfunc()`, once the function has been executed.

How can I end Gradio (in this case, `demo`) gracefully from within the column? I have found references to `gradio.Blocks.close()` and `gradio.Interface.close()` but the sources I found are sparse on details on how to implement this in my example.

My structure is:

```
import gradio as gr
demo = gr.Blocks(title="title")
with demo:
    with gr.Tab("tab"):
        with gr.Row():
            with gr.Column():
                myfunc()
                # Quit Gradio here

# Continue code execution here
my_next_func()
```

Please note that the Notebook is supposed to continue execute code after closing Gradio. Therefore I don't believe I can use `sys.exit()` or something similar as I think it will stop all code execution in the Notebook cell.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this

```
import gradio as gr

def my_function(input):
    output = ...
    return output

iface = gr.Interface(fn=my_function, inputs="text", outputs="text")
def on_close():
iface.set_on_close(on_close)
iface.launch()
iface.close()
```

I believe this should work

Answer (score 0):

not easy, I did another script to run the gradio app as subprocess so we can terminate:

```
    def launch_server():
        p = subprocess.Popen([
            "YOUR/python.exe", 
            "YOUR.py", 
            "--argExamplePort",
            "7860"
        ])

def run_server():
    p = None
    while True:
        try:
            settings = Settings()  # Create an instance of Settings
            reboot=settings.get_setting('reboot')=='on'
            if p is None or reboot:
                if reboot:
                    print ("rebooting")
                else:
                    print ("starting")
                settings.settings["reboot"] = 'off'
                settings.save_settings()
                if p is not None:
                    p.terminate()  # Terminate the process
                    time.sleep(sleeptime)  # Wait for 10 seconds
                p = launch_server()  # Start the server in a separate process


                p_minapi = launch_minapi()  # Start the gradio_image_mixerAPI script in a separate process
            time.sleep(sleeptime)  # Check restart_servera() every 5 seconds
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(sleeptime*2)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        run_server()
```

and the settings.py:

```
import json
import os

class Settings:
    DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
        "previewsize": 512,
        "reboot": "off"
    }

    def __init__(self, filename='settings.json'):
        self.filename = filename
        self.settings = self.load_settings()
        self.name = 'user' + os.getlogin()

    def load_settings(self):
        try:
            with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
                self.settings = json.load(file)
        except (FileNotFoundError, json.JSONDecodeError):
            self.settings = self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS
            self.save_settings()
        else:
            for key, value in self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS.items():
                self.settings.setdefault(key, value)
            self.save_settings()
        return self.settings

    def save_settings(self):
        # Save settings to the file
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(self.settings, file, indent=4)

    def update_setting(self, key, value):
        self.settings[key] = value
        self.save_settings()  # Save settings automatically when updated

    def get_setting(self, key, default=None):
        return self.settings.get(key, default)
```

then you can change settings in you app and set reboot = on to make the server restart:

```
        from settings import Settings
        settings = Settings()  # Create an instance of Settings
        settings.settings["previewsize"] = settingsPreviewSize
        settings.settings["reboot"] = 'on' 
        settings.save_settings()
```